# Average depth of linear features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dem, mapping, bathymetry

I have a shapefile with some linear features that I have drawn on the seafloor with QGIS. How can I calculate the depth of these in the field calculator (or another place)? I am looking for the average depth of each of the linear features. The seafloor map is an asc file, but I have tif and DEM of the same file if that for some reason could make it easier.

Comment: I guess you could buffer your line by some value coresponding to your DEM-resolution, then use `join by locations summary` on the buffer and the DEM, then `join attributes by location` the mean depth from the buffer to your lines.

Comment: Do you want want the average of the elevations at the vertexes of the linear feature or the average of all the elevation values from the raster along the linear feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drape to transfer the raster values to your line vertices as z-values.

(I used Densify by interval first to add more vertices.)

Field Calculate mean z value of your vertices with:

```
array_mean(array_foreach( 
     (generate_series( 1, num_points( $geometry))), z(point_n($geometry, @element))))
```

[image]