# QGIS Extracting Z-Values from vertex on line

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2threejs

I am trying to extract Z-values which have been draped from a raster DEM. I would like to access the individual vertex height values as shown in the image below preferrably in the field calculator

[image: vertex editor]

[image]

So far, I have tried using z(start_point($geometry)) in the field calculator, However, this only provides me the first z value (41.744) but I would like to access the other two vertex heights as well. I have tried using z($geometry), However the resulting value was null (not sure why, presumably due to the line not being a polyline).

For context I am trying to model a staircase in Qgis2threejs which has 3 different heights hence why I would like to access each vertex in the line individually)

Comment: Have you seen this answer [Average depth of linear features in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/416247/84455) already? With a bit of modification, you'll get `array_to_string(array_foreach(generate_series(1, 3), z(point_n($geometry, @element))))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used `array_to_string(array_foreach(generate_series(1, 3), z(point_n($geometry, 1)))`  as I figured @element was meant to be replaced with the index and it gave the output `'42.710739,42.710739,42.710739'` which is a little confusing as it is not the height value of any of the 3 z vertices and it only provides an array of 2 numbers